# how to adjust decimal places in sql query

Tags: sql-server, decimal

how can I make this output:

```
Total
      62809.44
        91686.34
        70671.29
```

to be

```
 $62.81
    $91.69
    $70.67
```

i want mo move the decimal places to the left 3 times, round and then add a character. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following

```
select '$' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), ROUND(70671.29/1000,2))
```

If you want to remove trailing zeros, try following.

```
select '$' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),CAST( ROUND(70671.29/1000,2) AS DECIMAL(5,2)))
```

Comment: @404notfound I'm glad it helped.

Comment: hi. suppose i have 0.25 how can I add only the $ sign? thanks.

Comment: @404notfound if i get your question, you would like following result `$0.25` . If so try following `SELECT '$' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),0.25)`

Comment: it shows error `Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '$0.55' to data type int.`

Comment: @404notfound It looks like you are trying to assign `CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),0.25)` to `int` . Notice that, `int` itself can not store `characters`, it can only store `number`, since `typeof` `CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),0.25)` expression is `nvarchar`, you get corresponding error. Try to use above expression in presentation layer.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    '$' + FORMAT(v / 1000, 'n2'), -- 2012+
    '$' + LEFT(CAST(v / 1000 AS DECIMAL(18,2)), 20) -- 2005+
FROM (
    VALUES
        (62809.44),
        (91686.34),
        (70671.29)
) t(v)
```

Output -

```
---------
$62.81   
$91.69   
$70.67
```

Comment: how about 2008? i am using 2008